# How to .appendChild() to all elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The blue **F** turns into an actual amount of weight when you enter a number into the input field above.

The Two Functions `Kg()` and `Lbs()` are changing the class `.dynamic` which is where Kg or Lbs is being appended to the 8 divs that have the `.dynamic` class. Now that's exactly what **isn't** happening. When I select the divs with the `.dynamic` class, It adds Kg or Lbs (whatever button I press) to the first element with the `.dynamic` class.

How do I make it so that it appends that to all of the elements with the `.dynamic` class?

```js
//Variables
const mercury = document.getElementById("mercury");
const venus = document.getElementById("venus");
const earth = document.getElementById("earth");
const mars = document.getElementById("mars");
const jupiter = document.getElementById("jupiter");
const saturn = document.getElementById("saturn");
const uranus = document.getElementById("uranus");
const neptune = document.getElementById("neptune");
const weight = document.getElementById("weight");

weight.addEventListener("input", Calc);

function Calc() {
  if (weight.value > 99999) {
    alert("Max Amount Of Numbers is 99999");
    weight.value = "";
  } else {
    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.38;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    mercury.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.9;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    venus.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 1;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    earth.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.38;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    mars.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 2.36;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    jupiter.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.92;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    saturn.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.89;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    uranus.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 1.12;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    neptune.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);
  }
}

function lbs() {
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit");
  if (unit == null) {
    let newElement = document.createElement("h3");
    newElement.setAttribute("class", "value");
    newElement.setAttribute("id", "unit");
    newElement.textContent = "Lbs";
    document.querySelector(".dynamic").appendChild(newElement);
  } else {
    if (unit.innerHTML == "Kg") {
      unit.innerHTML = "Lbs";
    }
  }
}

function kg() {
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit");
  if (unit == null) {
    let newElement = document.createElement("h3");
    newElement.setAttribute("class", "value");
    newElement.setAttribute("id", "unit");
    newElement.textContent = "Kg";
    document.querySelector(".dynamic").appendChild(newElement);
  } else {
    if (unit.innerHTML == "Lbs") {
      unit.innerHTML = "Kg";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
@font-face {
  font-family: SpaceQuest;
  src: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lemirq/WODP/master/Fonts/SpaceQuest-yOY3.woff);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: url(./dario-bronnimann-hNQwIirOseE-unsplash.jpg);
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.741);
  border-radius: 200px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

* {
  --c-light: #f4f4f4;
  --c-dark: #141414;
  --c-blue: rgb(10, 132, 255);
  --f-body: "Montserrat", system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  --trans-ease-in-out: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: var(--c-light);
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lemirq/WODP/master/images/dario-bronnimann-hNQwIirOseE-unsplash.jpg);
  margin: 0;
  inset: 50px;
  font-family: var(--f-body);
}

a {
  color: var(--c-light);
  text-decoration: none;
}


/***** NAVBAR *****/

.nav-item {
  transition: var(--trans-ease-in-out);
}

.ext-link {
  cursor: alias;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color: var(--c-dark);
  background-color: var(--c-light);
}

.nav-item:hover li {
  color: var(--c-dark);
}

.nav-item.icon-link:hover i {
  color: var(--c-dark);
}

.nav-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav-item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.gh-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
}


/***** End NAVBAR *****/


/***** Main *****/

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: SpaceQuest, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.input-group {
  border: 2px var(--c-light) solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* max-width: 400px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

[type="number"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

[type="number"] {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.2);
  border: none;
  font-family: var(--f-body);
  min-width: 280px;
}

.btn-form {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.2);
  border: none;
  transition: var(--trans-ease-in-out);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: var(--f-body);
}

.btn-form:hover {
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.4);
}

.btn-form:first {
  border-right: var(--c-light) 1px solid;
}

.input-group-text {
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.2);
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px;
}


/***** End Main *****/


/***** CARDS *****/

.card-container {
  margin: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: calc(100vw - 200px);
}

.card {
  background-color: #141414;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}

.planet-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.planet {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.planet-img {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

[src="./images/planets/Saturn.png"] {
  height: 79.25px;
  width: auto;
}

.weight {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.weight::after {
  content: ":";
}

.divider {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-color: var(--c-light);
}

.value {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: var(--c-blue);
}

.dynamic>.value:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.dynamic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/***** End CARDS *****/

.input-error {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>




<navbar>
  <ul class="nav-item-container">
    <a target="_blank" class="nav-item ext-link" href="https://lemirq.github.io">
      <li>Website</li>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" class="nav-item icon-link ext-link" href="https://github.com/Lemirq">
      <li><i class="bi bi-github gh-icon"></i></li>
    </a>

  </ul>

</navbar>
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="vs-h1">Your Weight On Different Planets</h1>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="weight" placeholder="Enter your Weight" type="number">
    <button id="kg" onclick="kg()" class="btn-form" type="button">Kg</button>
    <button id="lbs" onclick="lbs()" class="btn-form" type="button">Lbs</button>


  </div>

  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Mercury.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">mercury</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="mercury" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Venus.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">venus</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="venus" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Earth.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">earth</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="earth" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Mars.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">mars</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="mars" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Jupiter.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">jupiter</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="jupiter" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Saturn.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">saturn</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="saturn" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Uranus.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">uranus</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="uranus" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Neptune.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">neptune</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="neptune" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: just a quick thought here. If document.querySelector(".dynamic") returns an array of elements, then you'll need to iterate thru that array (and then apply appendChild() ). I just had something similar using document.getElementsByTagName() which returned an array.

Comment: The answers provide a much more efficient way of doing it but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Minor Problems

- There's no such HTML element `<navbar>`, there's `<nav>`.
- There's a block code hard-coded 8 times with the only difference between them is a number. Whenever code needs to repeat itself, we use some sort of iteration such as a `for` loop or an array method and the numbers would be passed as a single variable passed with every iteration.

```
const gforce = [0.38, 0.9, 1, 0.38, 2.36, 0.92, 0.89, 1.12];
for (let i=0; i < 8; i++) {
var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * gforce[i];//<== that should be a variable
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    venus.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);
}
```

Also, the `<input>` that's supposed to calculate lbs and kg doesn't appear to convert kg to lbs or vice-versa.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// An array of objects - each object represents a planet
const data = [{
    planet: 'Mercury',
    gforce: 0.38,
    img: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Mercury_in_true_color.jpg/440px-Mercury_in_true_color.jpg`
  },
  {
    planet: 'Venus',
    gforce: 0.9,
    img: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Venus_from_Mariner_10.jpg/440px-Venus_from_Mariner_10.jpg`
  },
  {
    planet: 'Earth',
    gforce: 1,
    img: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/The_Blue_Marble_%28remastered%29.jpg/440px-The_Blue_Marble_%28remastered%29.jpg`
  },
  {
    planet: 'Mars',
    gforce: 0.38,
    img: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg/440px-OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg`
  },
  {
    planet: 'Jupiter',
    gforce: 2.36,
    img: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg/440px-Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg`
  },
  {
    planet: 'Saturn',
    gforce: 0.92,
    img: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Saturn_during_Equinox.jpg/600px-Saturn_during_Equinox.jpg`
  },
  {
    planet: 'Uranus',
    gforce: 0.89,
    img: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Uranus_as_seen_by_NASA%27s_Voyager_2_%28remastered%29.png/440px-Uranus_as_seen_by_NASA%27s_Voyager_2_%28remastered%29.png`
  },
  {
    planet: 'Neptune',
    gforce: 1.12,
    img: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Neptune_-_Voyager_2_%2829347980845%29_flatten_crop.jpg/440px-Neptune_-_Voyager_2_%2829347980845%29_flatten_crop.jpg`
  }
];
// Reference <form> and all form controls
const conv = document.forms.converter;
const IO = conv.elements;
/*
Collect all tags with [name='planet'] and convert it into an array...
...iterate through array and define a htmlString and interpolate planet
name and <img> url...
...render htmlString into current <output>
*/
[...IO.planet].forEach((output, index) => {
  const html = `
  <h3>${data[index].planet}</h3>
  <img src='${data[index].img}'>
  <h4></h4>`;
  output.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
});

// Bind the "input" event to <form>
conv.oninput = IWC;

/*
Event handler passes Event Object by default
Reference all form controls
Reference the tag the user interacted with
If the user typed into [name='weight']...
...if that tag was also #lbs...
...#kg value is the value of >origin< times 0.45359237...
...otherwise #lbs value is the value of >origin< times 2.20462...
*/
/*
Collect all [name='planet'] into an array and iterate with .forEach()...
...clear out the last tag of current <output> (<h4>)...
...display the calculated totals for lbs. and kg of each planet
*/
function IWC(e) {
  const IO = this.elements;
  const origin = e.target;

  if (origin.name === 'weight') {
    if (origin.id === 'lbs') {
      IO.kg.value = +origin.value * 0.45359237;
    } else {
      IO.lbs.value = +origin.value * 2.20462;
    }
    [...IO.planet].forEach((output, index) => {
      output.lastElementChild.innerHTML = '';
      output.lastElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        `lbs. ${Math.round(data[index].gforce * IO.lbs.value)}<br>
     kg ${Math.round(data[index].gforce * IO.kg.value)}`);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1 Oswald;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #aaa
}

h1 {
  color: gold
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Raleway;
}

h3,
h4 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h4 {
  bottom: 0
}

form {
  margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 15px
}

fieldset+fieldset {
  background: #222
}

fieldset+fieldset legend {
  color: gold
}

output {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 24%;
  min-height: 8rem;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: black;
  color: cyan
}

input {
  font: inherit;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form id='converter'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <h1>Interplanetary<br>Weight Converter</h1>
    </legend>
    <input id="lbs" name='weight' placeholder=" Weight in lbs." type="number" min='0' max='99999'><label for='lbs'>lbs.</label>
    <input id="kg" name='weight' placeholder="Weight in kg." type="number" min='0' max='99999'><label for='kg'>kg</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <h2>The Solar System</h2>
    </legend>
    <output name='planet'></output>
    <output name='planet'></output>
    <output name='planet'></output>
    <output name='planet'></output>
    <output name='planet'></output>
    <output name='planet'></output>
    <output name='planet'></output>
    <output name='planet'></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You so much for this! I started coding a couple weeks ago so this feedback helps a lot!

Comment: Hey you didn't have any duplicated ids, you are ahead of the game 

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all elements with the .dynamic class by using querySelectorAll
2. Iterate through the NodeList and append desired child to each node

```
let dynamics = document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic")
dynamics.forEach((ele) => {
  let newElement = document.createElement("h3");
  ele.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The script must look something like this:

```
<script>
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic")
elements.forEach(el=>{
    let child = document.createElement('div')
    el.appendChild(child)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified quite a bit, the buttons' `innerHTML` values match what you want in the new unit elements.

```html
    <button id="kg" class="btn-form" type="button">Kg</button>
    <button id="lbs" class="btn-form" type="button">Lbs</button>
```

Use JavaScript to add an event listener to both unit buttons that call the same function which will update the `innerHTML` of the unit headings to match the clicked button. When initializing the unit heading elements you should not give them all the same `id` but rather a common `class` and you must also append a cloned copy of the element or it will just move the element form one spot to the next:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#kg, #lbs').forEach(ub => ub.addEventListener('click', units));

function units(e) {
  let units = document.querySelectorAll(".value.unit");
  if (units.length == 0) {
    let newElement = document.createElement("h3");
    newElement.setAttribute("class", "value unit");
    document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic").forEach((dyn) => {
      // append a cloned copy to each, not the same newElement
      dyn.appendChild(newElement.cloneNode())
    });
    // re-run the query to find the newly added nodes
    units = document.querySelectorAll(".value.unit");
  }
  // set the content
  units.forEach(unit => unit.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

```js
//Variables
const mercury = document.getElementById("mercury");
const venus = document.getElementById("venus");
const earth = document.getElementById("earth");
const mars = document.getElementById("mars");
const jupiter = document.getElementById("jupiter");
const saturn = document.getElementById("saturn");
const uranus = document.getElementById("uranus");
const neptune = document.getElementById("neptune");
const weight = document.getElementById("weight");

weight.addEventListener("input", Calc);

function Calc() {
  if (weight.value > 99999) {
    alert("Max Amount Of Numbers is 99999");
    weight.value = "";
  } else {
    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.38;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    mercury.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.9;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    venus.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 1;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    earth.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.38;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    mars.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 2.36;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    jupiter.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.92;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    saturn.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 0.89;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    uranus.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);

    var val = weight.value;
    console.log(val);
    var calculate = val * 1.12;
    calculate = Math.round(calculate);
    neptune.innerHTML = calculate;
    console.log(calculate);
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('#kg, #lbs').forEach(ub => ub.addEventListener('click', units));

function units(e) {
  let units = document.querySelectorAll(".value.unit");
  if (units.length == 0) {
    let newElement = document.createElement("h3");
    newElement.setAttribute("class", "value unit");
    document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic").forEach((dyn) => {
      // append a cloned copy to each, not the same newElement
      dyn.appendChild(newElement.cloneNode())
    });
    // re-run the query to find the newly added nodes
    units = document.querySelectorAll(".value.unit");
  }
  // set the content
  units.forEach(unit => unit.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
@font-face {
  font-family: SpaceQuest;
  src: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lemirq/WODP/master/Fonts/SpaceQuest-yOY3.woff);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: url(./dario-bronnimann-hNQwIirOseE-unsplash.jpg);
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.741);
  border-radius: 200px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

* {
  --c-light: #f4f4f4;
  --c-dark: #141414;
  --c-blue: rgb(10, 132, 255);
  --f-body: "Montserrat", system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  --trans-ease-in-out: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: var(--c-light);
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lemirq/WODP/master/images/dario-bronnimann-hNQwIirOseE-unsplash.jpg);
  margin: 0;
  inset: 50px;
  font-family: var(--f-body);
}

a {
  color: var(--c-light);
  text-decoration: none;
}


/***** NAVBAR *****/

.nav-item {
  transition: var(--trans-ease-in-out);
}

.ext-link {
  cursor: alias;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color: var(--c-dark);
  background-color: var(--c-light);
}

.nav-item:hover li {
  color: var(--c-dark);
}

.nav-item.icon-link:hover i {
  color: var(--c-dark);
}

.nav-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav-item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.gh-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
}


/***** End NAVBAR *****/


/***** Main *****/

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: SpaceQuest, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.input-group {
  border: 2px var(--c-light) solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* max-width: 400px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

[type="number"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

[type="number"] {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.2);
  border: none;
  font-family: var(--f-body);
  min-width: 280px;
}

.btn-form {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.2);
  border: none;
  transition: var(--trans-ease-in-out);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: var(--f-body);
}

.btn-form:hover {
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.4);
}

.btn-form:first {
  border-right: var(--c-light) 1px solid;
}

.input-group-text {
  background-color: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.2);
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px;
}


/***** End Main *****/


/***** CARDS *****/

.card-container {
  margin: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: calc(100vw - 200px);
}

.card {
  background-color: #141414;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}

.planet-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.planet {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.planet-img {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

[src="./images/planets/Saturn.png"] {
  height: 79.25px;
  width: auto;
}

.weight {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.weight::after {
  content: ":";
}

.divider {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-color: var(--c-light);
}

.value {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: var(--c-blue);
}

.dynamic>.value:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.dynamic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/***** End CARDS *****/

.input-error {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>




<navbar>
  <ul class="nav-item-container">
    <a target="_blank" class="nav-item ext-link" href="https://lemirq.github.io">
      <li>Website</li>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" class="nav-item icon-link ext-link" href="https://github.com/Lemirq">
      <li><i class="bi bi-github gh-icon"></i></li>
    </a>

  </ul>

</navbar>
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="vs-h1">Your Weight On Different Planets</h1>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="weight" placeholder="Enter your Weight" type="number">
    <button id="kg" class="btn-form" type="button">Kg</button>
    <button id="lbs" class="btn-form" type="button">Lbs</button>


  </div>

  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Mercury.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">mercury</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="mercury" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Venus.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">venus</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="venus" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Earth.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">earth</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="earth" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Mars.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">mars</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="mars" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Jupiter.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">jupiter</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="jupiter" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Saturn.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">saturn</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="saturn" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Uranus.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">uranus</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="uranus" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="planet-info">
        <img class="planet-img" src="./images/planets/Neptune.png" alt="EARTH">
        <h3 class="planet">neptune</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <h4 class="weight">weight</h4>
      <div class="dynamic">
        <h3 id="neptune" class="value">F</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```